# How I copy multiple worksheet and multiple chart obj sheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub cpySht2nWB()
Dim BkName As String
Dim NumSht As Integer
Dim BegSht As Integer

BegSht = 1

NumSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
BkName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .SaveAs FileName:="C:\E2EPerformance\test.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End With

For x = 1 To NumSht

    Workbooks(BkName).Sheets(x).Move _
    Before:=Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets(x)

Next
```

End Sub

it procedure error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Excel cannot insert the sheet into the destination workbook, because it contains fewer rows and column than the source workbook. To move or copy the data to the destination workbook, you can select the data, and then use the copy and paste commands to insert into the sheets of another workbook.

suppose: I have 10 worksheet and 10 chart object sheet
How i can fix this?

Comment: "it contains fewer rows and column than the source workbook", Which Excel version are you using??

Comment: I use Excel 2007, I have a only version 2007 in my computer @R3uK

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the end :
And if you also have charts sheets, Worksheets won't include them, use only Sheets

```
Sub cpySht2nWB()
    Dim BkName As String
    Dim NumSht As Integer
    Dim BegSht As Integer
    Dim NewBook As Workbook

    BegSht = 1

    NumSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    BkName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\E2EPerformance\test.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    End With

    For x = 1 To NumSht

        Workbooks(BkName).Sheets(x).Move _
        Before:=NewBook.Worksheets(NewBook.Worksheets.Count)

    Next x
End sub
```

Comment: I think that end isn't about this.

Comment: It's not working but I didn't use this function, thank a lot  @R3uK

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is not, plz be **far more clearer**. If it is plz validate answer to close subject